# В чем ирония в представленном предложении?

Tags: ирония

*По должности мельника дедушка Илья имел довольно близкое отношение к водяному, который заведовал нашими прудами, верхним и нижним, и двумя болотами* (Н. Лесков).

В чем ирония в этом предложении?

Comment: Нужно целиком задание.

Comment: Оно целиком здесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительное в шаге от мифического. Ирония фразы — в *естественности* распределения обязанностей: водяной заведует на объекте, где службу несёт реальное должностное лицо.

Comment: Но ведь ирония насмешку должна содержать. В чем насмешка?

Comment: Насмешка — действие, шутка над... Здесь, в этой фразе, действия нет. Если вы имели в виду усмешку, то она здесь предполагается ироничностью как реакция на сказанное.

Comment: Все равно не очень поняла(((

Comment: Хороший рассказчик анекдотов до наивности серьёзен, натурален, не играет лицом, намекая на желательное поведение слушателя в ответ на эффект в развязке. В концовке фразы из Лескова говорится совсем не с придыханием о водяном как хозяине вод, воплощении её страшной стихии, а буднично — о заведующем Водяном и вверенной ему водоохранной территории и его подчинённом.

Answer (score 0):

> Ирония - (греч. - притворство). Насмешливое выражение, состоящее в
> приписывании лицу или предмету качеств прямо противоположных тем,
> какими он обладает; насмешка в виде похвалы. Чудинов, 1910.

Для меня ирония этого предложения заключается в том, что водяной становится не мифическим существом, а своего рода бюрократом из мира духов.

То есть вот дедушка Илья, он мельник. Кто такой мельник? Ну это такой придаток к мельнице, а мельница нужна для много, потому что там хлеб мелят в муку, из муки делают хлеб, а хлеб все едят, то есть мельница - важное сооружение, . А мельник важен, только потому что он при мельнице. Был бы он не при мельнице, кто бы он был, никто, странноватый мужик с седой головой и большими усами?

И вот дедушка Илья начинает свой рассказ о потустороннем и выходит что: водяной - это бюрократ. И если еще следующее предложение прочитать, то становится ещё абсурднее: "Свою главную штаб-квартиру этот демон имел под холостою скрынью на нашей мельнице." То есть водяной, это такой демон-бюрократ уровня мельника или несколько богаче, так как у мельника один объект, а у водяного 2 хороших и 2 поплоше.

Он держит два озера и два болота, у него есть штаб-квартира, где он решает дела по данному ему хозяйству - рассказ дедушки Ильи переворачивает всё с ног на голову, выворачивая миф загадкой наружу, а знакомый мир погружая в глубину неизвестности. И этот абсурд обнажает бедность наших знаний о духовном мире и, бумерангом, обличает нашу уже слепоту в реальном мире. Смотрим на человека - видим мельника, придаток мельницы, смотрим на духовный мир - а видим верхнее озеро, нижнее озеро, болото, ну и водяного придатком этому хозяйству. Однако, дедушка Илья переносит стереотип представление о мельнике как придатке мельницы, на на мир духов, через метафору, чем вызывает понятийный коллапс и желание узнать дальше, что-то об обещанной тайне, что-то кроме притворства. Но это такой хитрый ход, потому что узнавая о потустороннем, мы узнаём не о водяном и других сущностях, а погружаемся во внутренний мир человека Ильи.(последнее не знаю, я не читал рассказ, навыдумывал больше)

Comment: А теперь бы краткий ответ услышать.

Comment: Краткий в начале 
"Для меня ирония этого предложения заключается в том, что водяной становится не мифическим существом, а своего рода бюрократом из мира духов." Водяной также относится к прудам, как дедушка Илья - мельник, то есть - "приписывании лицу или предмету качеств прямо противоположных тем, какими он обладает" - водяной, это как мельник, только из другого мира.